# PHPWORD and TCPDF convert file .DOCX in .PDF

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, docx, tcpdf, phpword

I everybody

i dont have any problem to create .docx fil with PHPWORD

now i want to convert the .docx file created in a .pdf file

im try this simple script but not working on my configuration:

```
      \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath('/PDF/tcpdf.php');
      \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('TCPDF');

      $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

      //Open template and save it as docx
      $document = $phpWord->loadTemplate('edited8.docx');
      $document->saveAs('temp.docx');

      //Load temp file
      $phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('temp.docx');

      //Save it
      $xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord , 'PDF');
      $xmlWriter->save('result.pdf');
```

i receive this error

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: PhpOffice\PhpWord\Exception\Exception

Message: PDF rendering library or library path has not been defined.

Filename: /application/php_word/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/Writer/PDF.php

Line Number: 50

[image]

anyone can help me ?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Of PDF renderer.
Are you using CodeIgniter? is my code in CodeIgniter:

```
$rendererName = Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
$rendererLibraryPath = APPPATH.('vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererName, $rendererLibraryPath);
```

I'm using DomPDF .. Just Custom a $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath.
Maybe it's right...